# Export html to docx with inline css using php

Tags: php

I don't know how to export data into .docx file using php and also apply inline css.

**I have tried**

```
<?php
    $filename = "Test Questions".date('d-m-Y');
    header("Cache-Control: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
    header("Pragma: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.docx");
?>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
        <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12">
        <meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 12">
    </head>

    <body>
        <table width="100%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid red;color:red;font-family: serif;">
            <tr>
                <td width="40%" align="left">left align</td>
                <td width="60%" style="text-align: right;">
                    right align
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

but not getting any css effect in .docx file.

Please anyone guide me. I really appreciate for your help. Thank you.

Comment: how about using this library https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord ?

Comment: then you can show us an error and update your question so that we can have a better idea about this error .. error does not mean it is not worth to use. :)

Comment: And more importantly, sample can not or should not contain error if it is in the documentation itself. . make sure you follow their guidelines to fulfil requirements.. all the best.

Comment: @Mittul At TechnoBrave You are absolutely correct. at this step my mistake. The error shows: 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not find file '/autoload.php'. It is generated by Composer. Use 'install --prefer-source' or 'update --prefer-source' Composer commands to move forward.' in bootstrap.php:22 Stack trace: #0 PHPWord-develop/samples/Sample_Header.php(2): require_once() #1 PHPWord-develop/samples/Sample_03_Sections.php(2): include_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 {main} thrown in bootstrap.php on line 22

Comment: it simply means that you need to understand how to install/configure it and use it :) .. go on and learn how to achieve this .. all the best ...

Comment: @Mittul At TechnoBrave where you have put code...? I run direct sample then shows upper given errors

Comment: have a look at this link https://www.codementor.io/php/tutorial/composer-install-php-dependency-manager

Comment: this one will or can also helpful to you https://www.dev-metal.com/composer-tutorial/